# influxdb and time precision

Tags: time, influxdb

I have some problems when write values to influxdb. Consider the following example

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write? db=devmessdaten&precision=rfc3339' --data-binary 'Pist,Anlage="ff4113bc-dec1-435c-9503-c31436dd98b8" value=0 2018-03-21T00:53:00Z'
```

and I'm getting a Bad timestamp

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: dfa5b762-3af5-11e8-87d8-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'Pist,Anlage="ff4113bc-dec1-435c-9503-c31436dd98b8" value=0 2018-03-21T00:53:00Z': bad timestamp
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.5.1
X-Request-Id: dfa5b762-3af5-11e8-87d8-000000000000
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 06:27:12 GMT
Content-Length: 127
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that InfluxDB expects dates in a epoch format -- seconds since the epoch. So your date stamp is actually 1521593580. If you use that date stamp in your insert, it works just fine.

Not sure what is generating your timestamp, but if you make sure it is in an epoch format, it will succeed.

Best regards, 
dg